# Dependencies not found for building opencv

Tags: dependencies

i am trying to follow up [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-python-source-with-opencv-and-opencv-contrib-ba95d709eb) tutorial to build opencv so i had to install dependencies first hence i opened a terminal and type the commands but some of them gives error , which are listed below:

sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio

```
root@raspberrypi:~# sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gstreamer1.0-qt5
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gstreamer1.0-qt5'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gstreamer1.0-qt5'
```

sudo apt -y install libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libtheora-dev

Error:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# sudo apt -y install libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libtheora-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libfaac-dev
```

any solution?

i am running raspberry pi 3b+ 
and the OS is [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/)

```
root@raspberrypi:~# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.75-v7+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:45:11 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Are your repositories updated? Try `sudo apt-get update` and then try these installs.

Comment: i did but the problem remains :(